# Transferring apps from computer to iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, mac, applications, data-transfer

I purchased a couple of apps on my Mac app store and wondered how I then transfer these over to my iPhone 4S to save having to pay for them again? I have synced my phone and Mac iTunes but nothing has changed.
Thanks! =)

Comment: Could you edit this to explain one app that is having problems installing. Also list the steps you took to configure app syncing in iTunes on the computer. Just syncing doesn't install specific apps depending on how you have iTunes set up for that iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

If you got them on the Mac app store, they're computer apps, and they won't work with your iPhone. If you're referring to iPhone apps purchased through iTunes, as long as you're signed in on the same Apple ID on your Mac and your iPhone, you can go to the "Purchased" tab on the iPhone app store and download you apps for free there. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: No, I got them on the Mac App Store not iTunes. But I have searched for them on my phone and they are available on there. Does that still mean I would have to purchase them again?